# Deduce template parameter for a template function pointer with default template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, language-lawyer, c++20

Though the question seems a little bit confusing. The code is simple as:

```
template <typename T>
void tfunc(T&& getter)
{

}

template <typename T = void>
void voidfunc()
{}

int main() {
    tfunc(&voidfunc);   // error: could not deduce template argument for 'T'
    tfunc(&voidfunc<int>); // ok
    voidfunc(); // calling using default template parameter is ok.
}
```

Both clang 11& msvc visual studio 2019 16.7 complains error.
Why I need to explicitly specify a template argument?

### Background

- the argument is a dummy parameter just to delay the instantiation of `voidfunc` to where it is used. The type doesn't really matter.
- `&voidfunc` is used by some code generated by clangAST, otherwise I need to tweak the generator to write `&voidfuc<>` if it is a template.
- `__declspec(property(put=voidfunc))` this clang/msvc extension however takes `voidfunc` but not `voidfunc<>`

I've tweaked the generator to output `&voidfunc<>` as @Jarod42 says, if the given function is a template. And it works for now.

Comment: `tfunc(&voidfunc<>);` is ok too if you want to use the default.

Comment: please include the full error message in the question. No error here https://godbolt.org/z/oaKfsxfnd (though that might be gccs fault)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number both clang and msvc complains error i've updated the question

Comment: @Jarod42 but i just want a plain &voidfunc will compile. because there is code generated by other tools using it this way

Comment: `voidfunc` is a function template, and there is no such thing as a pointer to a function template.

Comment: @Evg no but there is [\[temp.deduct.funcaddr\]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.deduct#funcaddr-1).

Comment: @rustyx - That is [p1972](https://wg21.link/p1972). But I'm not sure if this behavior really follows from that wording change.

Comment: What about something like `tfunc(static_cast<void(*)(void)>(&voidfunc));`? It'd leave it as `&voidfunc` although it ls even more to type.

Comment: @marekr [tag:language-lawyer] in [tag:C++] usually applies when the OP cares about what the standard says and who is right, not about finding a solution for a specific use case.  Here the OP has generated code and a problem, not a question about the standard, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I don't know, if it's pejorative or neutral? But I don't care about the tedious standard documents. I've made thing work by tweak the generator anyway. see my updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, this situation was not clear in the standard until C++20, where it was [cleaned up](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1972r0.html) in order to better support the new feature of constrained functions.  The new specification makes sense in previous language versions (ignoring the possibility of constraints), so hopefully implementations will eventually support this usage everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Template arguments for which template parameters have been defaulted, do not take part in template type deduction.
That is why you had to explicitly supply the template argument for voidfunc.

This was explained, as an aside, by Nicolai Josuttis in his 2017 cppcon talk on the "Nightmare of move semantics for trivial classes:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNRju6_yn3o&list=RDCMUCMlGfpWw-RUdWX_JbLCukXg&index=2

Comment: Please consider editing this link to link specifically to the timestamp where the speaker has this aside, and remove the playlist parameters of the query string.